# jQuery background image using CSS

Tags: jquery

```
function change_star_image(star_id){
    //$("#star_rating_image_"+star_id).css("background-image","url(images/full-star.png)");
    $("#star_rating_image_"+star_id).css('background', 'url(images/full-star.png)');
}
```

The background image is not changed. The above is my snippet.

Comment: Where is the HTML? Align your code properly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The jQuery looks fine. You should check :

- If the function is called correctly (use a debugger or add an alert)
- If "#star_rating_image_"+star_id is a valid element
- If the image is accessible

To do so, I recommend using the debuger of firebug.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is fixed. The stupid reason is, in server, the image was missing.

Comment: You shouldn't mark people down for marking you question down. I marked it down as it has come down to user error, it isn't a coding error.